# Search for a specific file and change to its directory

Tags: command-line, cd-command, cygwin

What's the best way to go to a directory that contains a specific file? (Assuming we are starting at the root of where we wish to search). I'm using Cygwin.

SOLUTION:
My final solution was to put this into my .bashrc file.

```
jump2_func() {
cd "$(find . -name $1 -printf %h -quit 2>/dev/null)"
}

alias jump2=jump2_func
```

Comment: You could write a script for this task.

Comment: I figure it's probably a small script I put in my .bashrc file.

Comment: @JohnGoofy But you cannot run that script regularly you have to `source` it.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I know, while reading this question I started to write a little file manager and I got my first non-rc file that needs to be sourced.

Comment: @Dale It is not recommended to blow up your `~/.bashrc` with lots of scripts. You can use an `alias` or use/`touch` `~/.bash_aliases` or `~/.bash_scripts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd "$(find . -name filename -printf %h -quit 2>/dev/null)"
```

If no file with this name is found then `cd` changes into the home directory. If that is not wanted then you need something like this:

```
dir="$(find . -name filename -printf %h -quit 2>/dev/null)"
test -d "$dir" && cd "$dir"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Now I'll just put this in an alias so I can jump to the files I need to in the project I have

Answer (score 6):

Two parts: Finding a file, and changing to the directory of a found file.

### Finding a file

If you have the name of a file that you'd like to locate somewhere in the file hierarchy on your system, there are two ways that immediately springs to mind:

1. Use `find`.
2. Use `locate`.

To locate a file using `find`:

```
$ find / -type f -name "filename" -print
```

This will wander through the whole filesystem from the root (`/`) down and print out the full paths of all regular files called `filename`. Change `/` to whatever directory path you'd like to search from.

To find a file using `locate`:

```
$ locate -r -b '^filename$'
```

This will output all paths of all files (and directories, etc.) whose name is `filename`. This is usually *much* faster than using `find`. I'm using `-r` and a regular expression here to match complete filenames, otherwise you may get matches like `file3` for a search of `file`. The `-b` option makes `locate` only match against the "base name" of the paths, i.e. the actual filename at the end of each path.

To be able to use `locate` on Cygwin, you would first have to initialize the "`locate` database".  You do this by running

```
$ updatedb
```

The downside with `locate` is that it only knows about the locations of files present when `updatedb` was run. This is why most Unix system with `locate` usually runs `updatedb` (or the equivalent command) using `cron` (which I don't think is available in Cygwin) at regular intervals; once a day on some Linuxes, or once a week as is the default on OpenBSD.

### Changing to the directory of a found file

Since neither of these methods are guaranteed to return only *one* file path, it's hard to come up with a sure-fire way of changing the working directory to the directory of the found file (if there are many, which one to choose?).

Assuming you'd like to pick the *first* result:

```
cd "$( dirname "$(somecommand | head -n 1)" )"
```

Here `somecommand` is either `find` or `locate` as above.

`head -n 1` will pick out the first result out of the list, and `dirname` will extract only the path of the directory that contains the file.  `cd` will then change the working directory to that directory.

Be aware that if you use `locate`, then the matches may also contain names of things that are not regular files (e.g. directories).

Comment: I agree that the updatedb would not work quite as well as I would like.  Using ' find . -name SignatureDocumentService.java' as an example, the output that comes out is './files/SignatureDocumentService.java'.  How can I cut off the last part so I can jump to the ./files directory?  (Of course I'm looking for something I can use as a single command like 'jumpToFile SignatureDocumentService.java'  )

Comment: @Dale He answered that already: see the command that contains `dirname`.

Comment: `find ... -printf "%h"` may also achieve the same effect for just retrieving the directory path string.